# How can you add multiple outputs from a pipe to a file as you go?

Tags: command-line, bash

I'm trying to print 4 different things at once using this.

`wc -l text.txt >processed.txt | cat text.txt | sort -r | tail -1 >>processed.txt | head -1 >>processed.txt | tail -5 | head -1 >>processed.txt`

My problem is that it only outputs the first > command to the file and the rest are ignored, I've tried moving them around to no avail. I would do it line by line for the 4 outputs but this is predicated by it needing to be one line.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make it one big pipeline: it looks like 4 separate operations all on the same file.  Each operation needs access to the original file contents.

```bsh
wc   -l text.txt >processed.txt
sort -r text.txt | tail -1 >>processed.txt
head -1 text.txt >>processed.txt
tail -5 text.txt | head -1 >>processed.txt
```

Or, group the commands together and have 1 redirection:

```bsh
{
    wc   -l text.txt
    sort -r text.txt | tail -1
    head -1 text.txt
    tail -5 text.txt | head -1 
} >processed.txt
```

If, as you write, it somehow needs to be on one line, add some semicolons:

```bsh
{ wc -l text.txt; sort -r text.txt | tail -1; head -1 text.txt; tail -5 text.txt | head -1; } >processed.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using [pee](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pee)

```
<text.txt pee 'wc -l' 'sort -r | tail -1' 'head -1' 'tail -5 | head -1' >processed.txt
```

`pee` is like [`tee` for commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/371730/65304)